# Create range from tuple (slice.indices())

Tags: python, python-2.7, range, slice

At the bottom of [this page](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) from the Python 2.3 docs it says:

> slice objects now have a method indices(length) which, given the length of a sequence, returns a (start, stop, step) tuple that can be passed directly to range()

Here is some test code:

```
s = slice(0, 10)
r = range(s.indices(10))
```

It throws a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got tuple.
```

Why doesn't this work?

In my use case, `range()` is called in a [library](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x/blob/master/python/neopixel.py#L42) and I need to supply a `slice` that is used this way.

Comment: that is not how it is used in your link it actually uses `range(*indices)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
r = range(*s.indices(10))
```

Explanation: `range()` expects up to three *integers* as arguments, so we need to unpack the *tuple of integers* returned by `indices()` using `*`, the splat operator.

Comment: Was just posting this! :) ++.

Comment: Does this mean that the library is currently broken? (Link in the question goes to the specific line of code)

Comment: range expects 1-3 integers